# Java String ReplaceAll (Regex Help)

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I have the following String:

```
String str1= "ABCD";
```

I want the following String

```
String str2 = "AD"
```

Therefore, I would like something along the lines of this:

```
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("/* SOME REGEX HERE */", "");
```

How can I write the regex so that both `"B"` and `"C"` are replaced?

Comment: Do you mean to replace all characters between A and D? Between the first and the last? Your problem is ambiguous.

Comment: I want to know how to replace any two characters with "".

Comment: @androideka sorry to ask, but can you undelete your last question (time difference in Java/Android)? I already have prepared an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as...

```
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("[BC]", "");
```